# Qt 5.12.0 MinGW 7.3 w64 cross compile from windows 64 to windows x86

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator, cross-compiling, mingw-w64

I have recently updated Qt to v 5.12.0. This version includes MinGW 7.3 W64 and there is not option to download MinGW 7.3 W32 as in previous version of Qt (see image below).

[image: Qt installer available tools]

I've built my application using QtCreator 4.8.1, and it was built without issues, however I noticed that my binary file is in 64 bits, and not in 32 bits like in previous version of Qt.

My problem is that I want to build my application for x86 platforms, but I can't find any options in Qt to do that. How can I cross compile my app for x86 using MinGW 7.3 w64 and QtCreator?

FYI: My OS is Windows 10 x64.

Comment: a partial solution can be found here: https://forum.qt.io/topic/97484/qt-5-12-make-mingw-32-release, however it requires to build a 32 bit version of Qt. That means each time you want to update QT you must build a 32 bit version by yourself. What i want is to use the mingw-64w compiler to build a 32 bits version of my application on windows x64.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to download the 32-bit version of mingw-64 separately

[sourceforge.net](https://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw-w64/files/Toolchains%20targetting%20Win64/Personal%20Builds/mingw-builds/5.3.0/)

After that you should configure your Qt Kits in Qt Creator.

Comment: This question was posted by me a long time ago. Maybe most answers are not correct because just know Qt pushed new releases for x64 and x32 as well. We only need to start the maintenance tool to download them and configure the kit.